# Create a Django's model which can have one of two types

Tags: django, django-models

I have a model `Client` which can be one of two types: `PJ` or `PF`. That means that a *Client* can have the fields of a `PJ` model or the fields of a `PF`model.

But I'm not sure how I can do it using the Django's **models** and **admin** app. I would like to give the user the option to select which type the *Client* is and then the appropriate fields will be shown to him/her.

Can someone help me with this problem? Should I use some kind of Design Pattern or how should I create my models?

*Thanks in advance.*

---

Model `PF`:

```
class PF(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=512)
    card = models.IntegerField(unique=True)
```

Model `PJ`:

```
class PJ(models.Model):
    ie = models.IntegerField(unique=True, null=True, blank=True)
```

Model `Client`:

```
class Client(models.Model):
    type = models.SmallIntegerField(default=0) # 0=PF, 1=PJ
```

Comment: I think you want to inherit Client. like `class PF(Client)` and `class PJ(Client)` Some reference: https://godjango.com/blog/django-abstract-base-class-multi-table-inheritance/

Answer (score 0):

First I'd recommend to look at the commonality between these two models and use inheritance if you can. If a type field is inevitable, I'd recommend using [CharField with choices](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.CharField) instead.

If the two models are drastically different, I'd recommend separating these two models completely, and call them InternalClient, ExternalClient, however the name would make sense to the data model.

Comment: Inheritance is something I usually avoid in Django because of the ORM's close ties to the database (and implicit complications when altering child classes in the future)... in this case I think having entirely separate classes is likely the best solution in the long term.